# Python 3 FTPLIB, NoneType Errors, and Uploads/Downloads

Tags: python, list, file-upload, download, ftplib

In my script I want to be able, in the end, to be able to download all files in a directory and all sub-directories... So I am trying FTPLIB. I'm trying to call dir of my ftp server and put it into a variable, but I get NONETYPE?! I can connect to the server and when I call directory = session.dir() It displays a kind of matrix style output in the console with files, read/write perms, dates, etc.... But when I then try to print Directory all I seem to get is "None". My initial idea was to for each item in the directory download them to my computer, but I can't seem to get a list of the directory!

```
directory = session.dir()
print(str(directory))
```

Sorry for the long and probably trivial explanation, but I have become a little bit too frustrated.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

-Clem

Comment: "Produce a directory listing as returned by the LIST command, printing it to standard output.... This method returns None". is what it says for `dir()`.  It does not return a value.  It prints something.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out that "Produce" part in their documentation. I've now fixed the problem. :)

Comment: @S.Lott Okay, It's very strange that it didn't work before, but thanks a lot S.Lott! I'm hopefully getting better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read this.  http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst

Then, try this:

```
directory = session.nlst()
print(directory)
```

Note.
You don't need to do `print(str(...))`.  The print function gets the string representation for you.

Comment: I just tried that and I get "<bound method FTP.nlst of <ftplib.FTP object at 0x100669110>>" Also I have been reading those documents extensively, but still haven't found an answer. Also 9000 I have just tried session.retrlines('list') to no avail. Sorry, I'm rather new to programming.

Comment: "<bound method FTP.nlst" usually means you forgot the ()'s.

Comment: It's strange this didn't work before hand... it does now... hmm. Perhaps just a flaw?

Comment: "Perhaps just a flaw? "?  Are you suggesting Python behaves randomly?  That's very unlikely.  More likely is you forgot the ()'s.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ftplib.html), the very first example shows how to do what you need: use `.retrlines('LIST')` to read the output of `LIST` command.

Another way is to use `.nlst()`.

Comment: Yes, I've read that several times, it's just I can't seem to make my program get each name of the files/dirs, I'm trying to find a way to for loop the downloads... :/